# Improving label collisions for Tree/Graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling, visualization, trees

Historically, MMA has never handled label collisions well, but recently they added some improvements here via things like `Callout`. I want to fix ImageSize but still see as much as possible (by tooltipping a minimal set of vertices).

Here's two examples of the problem:

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, `Callout` doesn't work in `Graphics` but it does on ListPlot type functions... any ideas?

Here's a starting point (some problems: callouts don't look like nice tree vertices labeled in-place, changing imagesize does not update callouts, below 200 imagesize doesn't look good...)

```
t=Tree["3271072249@1141.com", {Tree["7721267491@5233.com", {Tree["3374378456@1654.com", None], Tree["8156193455@7024.com", None], 
    Tree["2726956513@5582.com", None], Tree["8721814856@1953.com", None], Tree["7185180555@2326.com", 
     {Tree["1593982646@9063.com", None], Tree["9450325261@4285.com", {Tree["8975931949@1828.com", None], Tree["1050705225@4027.com", None], 
        Tree["5513025103@8209.com", None], Tree["1362791423@2283.com", None]}], Tree["1024253525@7814.com", 
       {Tree["6231800939@8967.com", None], Tree["194047936@6514.com", None], Tree["5501920321@2424.com", None], Tree["9409434183@5671.com", None], 
        Tree["8191299819@2444.com", None], Tree["1310407864@9363.com", None], Tree["3291603598@4060.com", None], Tree["6494419269@8541.com", None], 
        Tree["1423339331@4393.com", None], Tree["8184322126@6406.com", None], Tree["2774451387@6623.com", None], Tree["5904274758@3524.com", None]}], 
      Tree["1928449676@9927.com", {Tree["4384413123@3658.com", None], Tree["2852237777@4331.com", None], Tree["3046178790@8109.com", None], 
        Tree["7589029137@9484.com", None], Tree["192747158@7146.com", None], Tree["5895994753@8408.com", None], Tree["8811507189@3953.com", None]}], 
      Tree["5650327940@7688.com", {Tree["9203688553@2974.com", None], Tree["774154904@2674.com", None], Tree["5040588641@6468.com", None], 
        Tree["3992359567@7438.com", {Tree["1602898103@9030.com", None]}], Tree["1216211570@6291.com", None], Tree["2254391965@4419.com", None]}]}], 
    Tree["8811283459@4290.com", None], Tree["4767071314@8200.com", None], Tree["6604914590@4204.com", None], Tree["1814669756@8584.com", None], 
    Tree["6577822051@9921.com", None], Tree["6138724358@7727.com", None], Tree["3242609794@3531.com", None], Tree["9233171196@8124.com", None]}]}];

g = Graph@t;
vc = Association[(#[[2]] -> AnnotationValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]) & /@ 
    VertexList[g]];
vl = Association[#2 -> #1 & @@@ VertexList[g]];
ve = #1[[2]] -> #2[[2]] & @@@ EdgeList[g];
data = Values@Merge[{vc, vl}, Identity]; is = 300;
annotated = data /. {{a_, b_}, n_} :> Callout[{a, b}, n];
Slider[Dynamic[is], {100, 800}]
ListPlot[annotated, Axes -> None, 
 Prolog -> {LightGray, Line[List @@@ (ve /. vc)]}, ImageSize -> Dynamic[is]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is already a huge improvement!

Comment: Thanks, yes the tooltips are nice, but I would disagree... 1) the callouts are covering the edges 2) it doesn't have the styling of a Tree object 3) doesn't respond to ImageSize updates

Comment: I guess this is too hard for now...

Comment: I don't have Tree[..] on my system but for Tree styling and size updates: ```t = RandomInteger[#] ->  # + 1 & /@ Range[0, 30];```  ```Slider[Dynamic[is], {100, 1500}], Dynamic[is]}```  ```{Slider[Dynamic[ar], {0.05, 0.5}], Dynamic[ar]}``` ```Dynamic[g = 
  TreeGraph[t, VertexSize -> is/1800, AspectRatio -> ar, 
   EdgeStyle -> {Arrowheads[{is/130000}]}, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed[Automatic, Center, Tooltip], 
   ImageSize -> is]]```